# Can you call an Action Extension from the IOS 8 Mail App

Tags: ios, action, ios8, ios-app-extension

It is clear that the new IOS 8 action extensions have to be initiated by a user and from a system provided UI. My question is, will the IOS 8 Mail app have a system provided UI so that an action extension can be called when a user is reading an email or writing an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no. I did file a feature request for this, many opportunities for action extensions in Mail! I would suggest that you do the same to possibly get some priority behind this.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will put in a request as well. I would love to get this prioritized.

Comment: Out of curiosity Chris, how did you file a feature request? I submitted a request to https://www.apple.com/feedback/ Do you know of a better way?

Comment: @Hudor you should be using http://bugreport.apple.com for SDK related things like this